# Python 3.3 : Is it possible to put unicode characters on buttons with tkinter?

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to find a way to put unicode caracters on buttons.

For example, my idea was to do it like this:

```
checkButton = Button(root, height=5, width=10, image=u"\u2713")
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error:

```
File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2075, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "✓" doesn't exist
```

Does anybody know a way in which I could do such a thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the wrong property. `image` is for if you want a button with an image on it (it specifies the path to the image). You want the `text` property. Try:

```
checkButton = Button(root, height=5, width=10, text=u"\u2713")
```

And according to http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/UnicodeSupport:

> For most systems, Tkinter should accept unicode strings and render
>   them more or less properly

See also http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

Comment: This, of course, depends on you having a font that has the appropriate glyph.